# How to pass webform querystring parameter to mvc application

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an Asp.net 4.0 application WebForm that needs to call a MVC View. Can I pass values to MVC in a QueryString Paramater (../Mvc/Recall?ID=1)?

I have control of source for both applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is how you would do it. Then on the MVC side, you would have a controller and action method.

Controller:

```
public class MvcController : Controller
```

Action method:

```
public ActionResult Recall(int id)
{

    return View();
}
```